# joi v17.4.1, Validate only mentioned or required field , all other params should be options

Tags: node.js, joi

I'm using  joi v17.4.1,to validate post input body parameters , but i want to only put the required parameters in JOi Schema
For example , for Registration i need only username, Email and Password to be mandatory all others parameters will be options .
So i'm creating joi schema like :

```
const registerUserValidator = async (body) => {
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    username: Joi.string()
        .alphanum()
        .min(3)
        .max(30)
        .required(),

    password: Joi.string()
        .pattern(new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$')),

    repeat_password: Joi.ref('password'),

    email: Joi.string()
        .email({ minDomainSegments: 2, tlds: { allow: ['com', 'net'] } })
})
```

There user can post :

```
{
    "username":"myuserName",
    "name":"Test Name",
    "email":"test@email.com",
    "phone":"00000000",
     "password":"12345",
     "repeat_password":"12345",
}
```

> **I'm getting error** :

```
{
    "messeage": "\"name\" is not allowed"
}
```

**> Please help**

Answer (score 1):

You can also ignore every other field with the options passed in like so:

```
const registerUserValidator = async (body) => {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        username: Joi.string()
            .alphanum()
            .min(3)
            .max(30)
            .required(),

        password: Joi.string().pattern(
            new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$")
        ),

        repeat_password: Joi.ref("password"),

        email: Joi.string().email({
            minDomainSegments: 2,
            tlds: { allow: ["com", "net"] },
        }),
    });

    return schema.validate(body, {
        abortEarly: false,
        allowUnknown: true,
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

just add other fields with Joi.allow() as shown below:

```
const registerUserValidator = async (body) => {
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    username: Joi.string()
        .alphanum()
        .min(3)
        .max(30)
        .required(),

    password: Joi.string()
        .pattern(new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$')),

    repeat_password: Joi.ref('password'),

    email: Joi.string()
        .email({ minDomainSegments: 2, tlds: { allow: ['com', 'net'] } }),

    //add this in your code
    phone:Joi.allow(),
    name:Joi.allow()
})
```